# printing v shape in java

Tags: java, algorithm

I am a newbie to java programming and I am working on this excercise from my textbook. The goal is to print a `V` shape pattern of numbers. From the picture below, you can see what the output should look like. I am having trouble creating the other half of numbers. I have pasted my code down below for reference.

[image]

```
for (int i = 7; i >= 1; i--) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) { 
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    System.out.print(i);

    for (int k = 1; k >= i*2; k++) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code (just made a few modifications to your code, did not check its efficiency):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 7; i >= 1; i--) {
        for (int k = 7; k >= i; k--) {
            System.out.print(" ");  // Print 7-i number of spaces before start of each line
        }
        System.out.print(i); // Print i
        for (int j = 1; j <= i*2; j++) {
            System.out.print(" "); // Print i*2 number of spaces after printing i
        }
        System.out.println(i); // Print i
    }
}
```

Comment: Please take the time to explain your code. Code only answers are discouraged.

Comment: bless your soul @S.K.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Doing people’s homework should be equally frowned upon.

Comment: I think he had a decent attempt at it :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather then nesting loops (and iterating backwards), I would decompose the generating of white-space with a method to repeat a given `String` a given number of times. Like,

```
private static String repeat(String s, int n) {
    return Stream.generate(() -> s).limit(n).collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

Then I would prefer a `StringBuilder` and a single call to `println` like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int start = 6;
    for (int i = 0; i < start; i++) {
        int v = start - i;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(repeat(" ", i)).append(v);
        sb.append(repeat(" ", 2 * v)).append(v);
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```